# What do these hash/pound symbols in the Sequelize docs represent?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

My team is investigating javascript ORM frameworks for use in an upcoming project but I can't figure out what the heck these # symbols mean in the [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/) docs but I know this is invalid JS.

Here is an example taken from the [docs here](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/associations/#one-to-one-associations):

```js
// this will add the attribute DadId to Person
Person.hasOne(Person, {as: 'Father', foreignKey: 'DadId'})

// In both cases you will be able to do:
Person#setFather
Person#getFather
```

I've likely missed something within their documentation but I can't find any reference that is of any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common way to document methods of a class.

In this case, the documentation is saying:

```
The Person class has an instance method named setFather
The Person class has an instance method named getFather
```

This is idiomatic in Ruby, I've never personally seen it used for JS

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful but if I understand you correctly that should allow me to do `Person.getFather()` but when I tried that I get the typical "Person.getFather is not a function"... but being new to Sequelize it could be that I've done something wrong. All this to say, if this is the only answer in a few hours I'll accept it. :)

Comment: It's because you were trying to call the function as a "class method", when it's an instance method. You would need to create a person first: `var p = new Person(); p.getFather();`